# Infragistics UltraGrid not functioning

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm trying to use Infragistics' UltraGrid control. When I drag the control on the form it shows at the bottom(where controls with no look appear). And it is not visible in on the form. I'm using infragistics 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [forum post](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/40136/226277.aspx) may help, but some common causes include:

1. Design assemblies could not be found
2. Multiple copies of an assembly with the same version are installed in the GAC

Comment: Well when I try uninstalling it say gacutil could not be found

Comment: @Antarr - Read through the entire post "Turned out to be multiple versions of the same assembly in the GAC. The uninstall kept exploding about not being able to find gacutil.exe and I ultimately had to manually delete everyting from the registry and then the GAC and re-install the version we specifically needed. Good times ;)"

Comment: You deleted using regedit? and how do you reinstall the gac? will deleting gac interfere with anything else.

Comment: @Antarr - I didn't go through this. The person who posted on that forum that had the same issue did. Their solution was to uninstall completely, but apparently due to a issue with Infragistic's installer they had to do the GAC part manually.